# Time units returned from timeit

Tags: python-3.x, microbenchmark, timeit

At the first glance, Python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/timeit.html# suggests that the time units returned by `timeit` with default parameters are the ones of the default timer `time.perf_counter()`, which are `fractional seconds`. I couldn't find anything to the contrary on that page, but a simple test:

```
>>> timeit('3**2')
0.007580029021482915
```

suggests `usec`. What have I missed?

Comment: **timeit(number=1000000)**
Time number executions of the main statement. This executes the setup statement once, and then returns the time it takes to execute the main statement a number of times, **measured in seconds as a float.**  [its seconds as documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seconds. You missed that that's the time for the default one million executions (`number=1000000`).

Comment: Thank you. I missed that link.